# Can't use mobile data on non-default sim, even if inactive when the second sim is open call

Tags: mobile-data, sim-card, data-connection, dual-sim

I'm using OnePlus 7T with dual sim.
Sim #1 is my default sim, and Sim #2 is a data sim which I'm using only for mobile data.
Obviously, I've defined Sim #1 to be the default sim for calls and sms, and Sim #2 to be the default sim for data.

When I'm in an active call on Sim #1, Sim #2 is automatically blocked.
However, instead of using Sim #1 for data, the phone is simply not getting any mobile data at all.

Any ideas on tackling this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you can specify the connection type for SIM #1 try to set it so that LTE is disabled for SIM#1. LTE has no voice part. If a call comes in the device can make use VoLTE (which requires a data connection on SIM#1) or drop SIM#1 connection to 2G/3G. Based on your description I would assume it uses VoLTE which then collides with data from SIM#2. an the VoLTE connection only can only be used for voice data, hence no Internet connection.

Comment: Sim #1 uses 2G\3G on calls (no VoLTE).

I think the phone can't use data from Sim #2 since OnePlue 7T is DSDS (dual sim dual standby), meaning it can't actively use Sim #2 when Sim #1 is in call.

I just don't understand whey it doesn't just tries to use Sim #1 for data. (which do happen when I choose Sim #1 as my default data sim as well)

Answer (score 0):

It all depend on your network strength and ability to handle voice + data.
Like 4G VoLTE has no issue about this. It can handle voice and mobile data simultaneously.
If you have other network, then make sure in your area network strength is high and your sim provider can handle both voice and data simultaneously.
Also mobile hardware and android os has features to handle voice + data.

Comment: So in your opinion this is totally independent of the fact that the phone is a dual-sim card phone (because you mentioned anything about that fact in your answer)?

Comment: But when my default data sim is the same sim I use for calls, I am able to use the internet even when I'm in active call (and not only on VoLTE)